# Push an array into an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new in JavaScript and I want to transform this array `["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"]`, in this one `[["Banana"], ["Orange"], ["Apple"], ["Mango"]]`, but when I try to do it, my browser freezes. I'm using this code:

```
<script>
var i = 0;
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

function myFunction() {
    var fruits_aux = [];
    for (i=0; fruits.length; i++)
      fruits_aux.push([fruits[i]]);
    fruits = fruits_aux;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
}
</script>
```

Be careful executing this code. Anyone can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `for` loop, the condition always evaluates to `true`, hence, it becomes an infinite loop and the reason for your browser freeze.

```
for (i=0; fruits.length; i++)
```

should probably be

```
for (i=0; i < fruits.length; i++)
```

Comment: Glad to hear that - please accept it as answer if it solved the issue for you.